# doctrine property mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I just started working with symfony and doctrine. I have a simple entity which has one property is not tied with the database. This property should contain the contents of the xml file (I wanna make xml file, when doctrine add rows to the database).

```
/**
 * Layouts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="layouts")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Layouts
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="layouts_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * ???????
     */
    private $template_body;
    ...
}
```

How to describe `$template_body` property? Without leaving the property description, I ran into a problem - the doctrine does not cause preUpdate method when I edit this property in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that my simply flagging a PreUpdate method in your class, which in turn begins working on your $template_body variable.

Please change

```
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
```

to

```
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
```

and create a function like so..

```
/**
 * @PreUpdate
 */
public function myUpdateFunction()
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: If i edit only $template_body value in my admin form @PreUpdate method is not called. 
But if i edit something else - PreUpdate method work fine. I think problems with mapping.

Comment: $template_body is not a part of the ORM column set, so editing just this value on a managed Entity will not trigger the PreUpdate event. I think the question you need to ask, is what are you actually going to do with $template_body once its created, is it to be persisted with other attributes of that entity? If so should it not also be a column?

Comment: "$template_body is not a part of the ORM column set, so editing just this value on a managed Entity will not trigger the PreUpdate event. I think the question you need to ask" - thanks, you right!

I want create file on my disk from $template_body attribute and i do it with trigger the PreUpdate event. But if i editing just this value on a managed Entity will not trigger the PreUpdate event. This is my problem. English my second problem, i so sorry((

Comment: Well if editing that value (only) is what triggers the update, should it be part of an entity at all? I'd argue that value should solely be reserved for writing too when the Entity is updated (via other setters). Remember doctrine will only save something if when calculating a "changeset" in the unit of work there is a change present.